# How do i loop over FileInfo[] and update the Paint event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pixelscoordinatesinrectangle = new List<Point>();
            pixelscoordinatesinrectangle = pointsAffected.ToList();
            DrawIt = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < trackBar1FileInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                DrawIt = true;
                trackBar1.Value = i;
                LoadPictureAt(trackBar1.Value, sender);
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                pixelscoordinatesinrectangle = pointsAffected.ToList();
                MessageBox.Show(pixelscoordinatesinrectangle.Count.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**`trackBar1FileInfo is FileInfo[]`** and contain 5006 files inside for example in

```
index 0 I see test.gif 
index 1 I see test1.gif 
index 2 test2.gif 
and so on....
```

In the trackBar1 sroll event when i'm moving the trackBar left and right it's changing the images in the pictureBox1.

LoadPictureAt is:

```
private bool LoadPictureAt(int nIndex, object c)
        {

            {
                bool bRet = false;

                if (nIndex >= 0 && nIndex < trackBar1FileInfo.Length)
                {
                    if (c.Equals(trackBar1))


                        pictureBox1.Load(trackBar1FileInfo[nIndex].FullName);
                    bRet = true;

                }
                if (bitmaps != null)
                {
                    if (nIndex >= 0 && nIndex < bitmaps.Length)
                    {
                        if (c.Equals(trackBar2))
                            pictureBox1.Image = bitmaps[nIndex];
                        bRet = true;
                    }
                }
                return bRet;

            }
        }
```

I'm using the method LoadPictureAt in the trackBar1 scroll event to display the images.

**`pixelscoordinatesinrectangle`** is List

In the paint event i have:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cloudPoints != null)
            {
                if (DrawIt)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                    pointsAffected = cloudPoints.Where(pt => rect.Contains(pt));

                    CloudEnteringAlert.pointtocolorinrectangle = pointsAffected.ToList();
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    CloudEnteringAlert.Paint(e.Graphics, 1, 200, bmp);
                }
            }   
        }
```

The problems are:

1. The images in the pictureBox1 not changing when it's doing the loop.
2. The List pixelscoordinatesinrectangle never change if it was with 203 items it will stay with 203 items.

The idea here is to loop over all the images and update the pictureBox1 and doing the paint event code so each time each image the List **`pixelscoordinatesinrectangle`** will update also.

What happen now is that only the trackBar1 is moving to 0 and then moving up one by one value. All the others not change.

Comment: I see using breakpoint that it's getting each time to the paint event but the List of Points never change same count same pixels coordinates inside. Something in the loop is wrong maybe with the values i give in to the LoadPictureAt method.  In the Paint event it should daw the rect on each image and get the pixels coordinates inside. But in fact the List never change and also the images in the pictureBox never change only the trackBar1 value change.

Comment: The problem might be that you're running everything from the main thread, so even if you call `Refresh` on the picture box, the application has no time to actually repaint it. But I haven't tested your code, so it might well be something else.

Comment: Placing a breakpoint in a Paint event handler can be problematic - you're asking Windows to temporarily stop updating the bits that are about to become part of one window's display while Visual Studio debugger takes over the Windows UI and displays debugging info. An alternative debugging technique is to place logging statements in the Paint event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is blocking on the main UI. Use a seperate thread/background worker to update. Take a look here, possible duplicate: [Creating a statusfield for users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918302/creating-a-statusfield-for-users/29918424#29918424)